# AWS Lambda (Python Zappa) Understanding the Logs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zappa

Zappa is a beautiful piece of code that makes your code serverless without anything to code.

I'm trying to understand the intricacies of Zappa, and I would like to start with the Logging. I'm successful in deploying my Python Django App on AWS Lambdas. Following are the logs which I'm not able to understand. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
1589392413834] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.834Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing BlpImagePlugin
[1589392413854] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.854Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing BmpImagePlugin
[1589392413894] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.894Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing BufrStubImagePlugin
[1589392413896] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.896Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing CurImagePlugin
[1589392413896] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.896Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing DcxImagePlugin
[1589392413898] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.898Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing DdsImagePlugin
[1589392413900] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.900Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing EpsImagePlugin
[1589392413915] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.915Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing FitsStubImagePlugin
[1589392413915] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.915Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing FliImagePlugin
[1589392413933] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.933Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing FpxImagePlugin
[1589392413935] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.935Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Image: failed to import FpxImagePlugin: No module named 'olefile'
[1589392413935] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.935Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing FtexImagePlugin
[1589392413936] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.935Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing GbrImagePlugin
[1589392413936] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.936Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing GifImagePlugin
[1589392413955] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.955Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing GribStubImagePlugin
[1589392413973] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.973Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing Hdf5StubImagePlugin
[1589392413974] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:33.974Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing IcnsImagePlugin
[1589392414013] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.0Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing IcoImagePlugin
[1589392414015] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.15Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing ImImagePlugin
[1589392414035] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.35Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing ImtImagePlugin
[1589392414036] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.36Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing IptcImagePlugin
[1589392414037] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.37Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing JpegImagePlugin
[1589392414180] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.180Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing Jpeg2KImagePlugin
[1589392414180] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.180Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing McIdasImagePlugin
[1589392414193] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.193Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing MicImagePlugin
[1589392414194] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.194Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Image: failed to import MicImagePlugin: No module named 'olefile'
[1589392414194] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.194Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing MpegImagePlugin
[1589392414195] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.195Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing MpoImagePlugin
[1589392414196] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.196Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing MspImagePlugin
[1589392414214] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.214Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing PalmImagePlugin
[1589392414218] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.217Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing PcdImagePlugin
[1589392414218] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.218Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing PcxImagePlugin
[1589392414218] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.218Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing PdfImagePlugin
[1589392414276] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.276Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing PixarImagePlugin
[1589392414293] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.293Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing PngImagePlugin
[1589392414293] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.293Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing PpmImagePlugin
[1589392414294] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.294Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing PsdImagePlugin
[1589392414296] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.296Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing SgiImagePlugin
[1589392414298] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.297Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing SpiderImagePlugin
[1589392414299] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.299Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing SunImagePlugin
[1589392414300] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.300Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing TgaImagePlugin
[1589392414314] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.314Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing TiffImagePlugin
[1589392414314] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.314Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing WebPImagePlugin
[1589392414336] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.336Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing WmfImagePlugin
[1589392414338] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.338Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing XbmImagePlugin
[1589392414340] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.340Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing XpmImagePlugin
[1589392414354] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:34.354Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Importing XVThumbImagePlugin
[1589392416528] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.528Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Changing event name from creating-client-class.iot-data to creating-client-class.iot-data-plane
[1589392416532] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.532Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Changing event name from before-call.apigateway to before-call.api-gateway
[1589392416532] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.532Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Changing event name from request-created.machinelearning.Predict to request-created.machine-learning.Predict
[1589392416547] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.547Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Changing event name from before-parameter-build.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration to before-parameter-build.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration
[1589392416547] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.547Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Changing event name from before-parameter-build.route53 to before-parameter-build.route-53
[1589392416547] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.547Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Changing event name from request-created.cloudsearchdomain.Search to request-created.cloudsearch-domain.Search
[1589392416548] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.548Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Changing event name from docs.*.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section to docs.*.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section
[1589392416568] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.567Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Changing event name from before-parameter-build.logs.CreateExportTask to before-parameter-build.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask
[1589392416568] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.568Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Changing event name from docs.*.logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section to docs.*.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section
[1589392416568] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.568Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Changing event name from before-parameter-build.cloudsearchdomain.Search to before-parameter-build.cloudsearch-domain.Search
[1589392416568] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.568Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Changing event name from docs.*.cloudsearchdomain.Search.complete-section to docs.*.cloudsearch-domain.Search.complete-section
[1589392416572] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.571Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Looking for credentials via: env
[1589392416572] [INFO] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.572Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Found credentials in environment variables.
[1589392416573] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.573Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/endpoints.json
[1589392416609] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.608Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f582245f158>
[1589392416631] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.630Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/lambda/2015-03-31/service-2.json
[1589392416648] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.648Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Event creating-client-class.lambda: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f582252d8c8>
[1589392416668] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.668Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Setting lambda timeout as (60, 60)
[1589392416669] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.669Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/_retry.json
[1589392416670] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.670Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Registering retry handlers for service: lambda
[1589392416674] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.670Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f582245f158>
[1589392416674] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.671Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/sns/2010-03-31/service-2.json
[1589392416674] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.673Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Event creating-client-class.sns: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f582252d8c8>
[1589392416688] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.687Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Setting sns timeout as (60, 60)
[1589392416689] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.688Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Registering retry handlers for service: sns
[1589392416707] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.707Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f582245f158>
[1589392416708] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.708Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/sts/2011-06-15/service-2.json
[1589392416709] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.709Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Event creating-client-class.sts: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f582252d8c8>
[1589392416711] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.711Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Setting sts timeout as (60, 60)
[1589392416712] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.712Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Registering retry handlers for service: sts
[1589392416712] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.712Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f582245f158>
[1589392416713] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.713Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/dynamodb/2012-08-10/service-2.json
[1589392416748] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.747Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Event creating-client-class.dynamodb: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f582252d8c8>
[1589392416750] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.749Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Setting dynamodb timeout as (60, 60)
[1589392416751] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:36.750Z e4fe02dc-8707-42ec-b9c8-927722bbe9da Registering retry handlers for service: dynamodb
[1589392417287] /var/task/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
[1589392417287] """)
[1589392417375] /var/task/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
[1589392417375] """)
[1589392420473] [DEBUG] 2020-05-13T17:53:40.473Z 87a3402e-83c0-46c4-8321-83dfb5894ac4 Zappa Event: {'time': '2020-05-13T17:52:45Z', 'detail-type': 'Scheduled Event', 'source': 'aws.events', 'account': '305248833490', 'region': 'ap-south-1', 'detail': {}, 'version': '0', 'resources': ['arn:aws:events:ap-south-1:305248833490:rule/4cc28a00df50496a4bbc3925ba41efa0a6d64-handler.keep_warm_callback'], 'id': '3033db8b-a8db-d250-7aa3-62d57ac09bab', 'kwargs': {}}
```

What is

1) Importing XYZPlugin

2) Changing event name from X to Y

3) Loading JSON file:

4) Event creating-client-class.sns: calling handler

Comment: Sounds like you will need to dig into the Zappa code, or ask for more information at their GitHub repo.